How to charge proration free on subscription revise paypal
I'm building a feature to allow users to upgrade their plans with proration in paypal. But I can't figure out how to charge them a proration fee I calculated
Here is what I've tried
Assume that this is a call to /v1/billing/subscriptions/{sub}/revise?
  request.requestBody({
    plan_id: event.parsed_body.planId,,
    application_context: {
      brand_name: 'Sample brand name',
      locale: 'en-US',
      shipping_preference: 'SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS',
      user_action: 'SUBSCRIBE_NOW',
      payment_method: {
        payer_selected: 'PAYPAL',
        payee_preferred: 'IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED',
      },
      return_url: process.env.HOME_URL + '/infos/subscriptions?upgrade=1',
      cancel_url: process.env.HOME_URL + '/?cancel=1',
    },
    plan: {
      "billing_cycles": [
        {
          "frequency": {
            "interval_unit": "YEAR",
            "interval_count": 1
          },
          "tenure_type": "TRIAL",
          "sequence": 1,
          "total_cycles": 1,
          "pricing_scheme": {
            "fixed_price": {
              "value": Number(prorationDetails.prorate_fee).toFixed(2),
              "currency_code": "USD"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "frequency": {
            "interval_unit": "YEAR",
            "interval_count": 1
          },
          "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
          "sequence": 2,
          "total_cycles": 0,
          "pricing_scheme": {
            "fixed_price": {
              "value": Number(prorationDetails.next_billing.amount).toFixed(2),
              "currency_code": "USD"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
    }
  });

  let response = await client.execute(request);

This is me trying to charge them the proration fee for the trial period but then moving them to a normal cycle. This results in a error from paypal saying "The provided billing cycle sequence is not available"
